# Checking for bracketed varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I'm trying to pattern match a string that would look like this:

```
[I am a varchar contained in brackets]
```

This doesn't work:

```
LIKE '[[]%[]]'
```

Is my only option to use 2 and statements:

```
LIKE '%[]]' AND LIKE '[[]%'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're escaping special characters correctly.  Here's how you can do it:

```
where foo like '\[%\]' escape '\'
```